# If HTML Populated dynamically, need to Encode Email Address Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

So I have a pretty much bare HTML page, have an empty div tag that is populated when the window loads.

I've read that we should encode user emails to reduce spam. My page has the following HTML:

```
<div id="email"></div>
```

I dynamically populate the content such as:

```
document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = "<a href=...>"
```

Do I even need to further encode the emails using javascript when rendering the page?

Comment: You are filling an `a` tag with another `a` nesting a link inside a link

Comment: @Onimusha Thanks for the heads up, have changed the above code snippet for more clarity. a => div

Comment: spambots are pretty clever these days. They can just wait for the page to load and inspect the DOM for any `a` that are `mailto:` links. This is trivial to do with something like phantomjs. I generally find the best place to fight spam is at the email server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Matt Greer in the comment above.

Personally, I would not make any emails readable online even via javascript. If it's required for any project then make it visible to registered members only. If your registration process is secure enough and spam free then so will the emails.

Then a basic javascript implementation such as the above will be quite secure.

Comment: If spammers are sophisticated as Matt Greer noted, DOM loaded => download the page and search for emails, I guess I am only left with one option: inconvenience my users to press a button first in order for JS to display the email.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a script like this. Any bot that can run Javascript will still have access to the email, but since the `<a>` tag and email address aren't visible anywhere in the source code,  bots which just download the HTML and then scan it for email addresses will not notice the email address.

```
<script>
    (function(d){
        var s = d.getElementsByTagName('script');
        s = s[s.length - 1];

        var a = d.createElement('a');
        a.href = rot13('znvygb') + '\x3a' +
          rot13(arguments[2]) +  '\x40' + rot13(arguments[3]);
        a.innerHTML = arguments[1];

        s.parentNode.insertBefore(a, s);

        function rot13(s){
            return s.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,function(c){return String.fromCharCode((c<="Z"?90:122)>=(c=c.charCodeAt(0)+13)?c:c-26);});
        }

    })(document, 'Send Email', 'wbuaqbr', 'tznvy.pbz');
</script>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rj2TE/)

Comment: Thanks for this tidbit of code. Do you have the first part of the script that generates the "wbuaqbr" and "tznvy.pbz" for johndoe@gmail.com? Specifically the going forward 13 letters?

Comment: @invulnarable27 Sorry. I forgot to explain. You can just use rot13 again to get those strings. If you only want to do it for one email address you can just use this site: http://www.rot13.com/